# MissingRuntimeArtifactException on Xamarin.Forms App with .Net Native Toolchain Enabled

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, .net-standard-2.0

i've a Xamarin.Forms application (UWP, using .Net Standard 2.0; Target Windows Version: 10 Fall Creators Update), that runs perfect without .NET Native toolchain. But when i enable the .Net Native Toolchain in the project settings, i retrieve exceptions during runtime:

```
System.Reflection.MissingRuntimeArtifactException: 'Cannot retrieve a MethodInfo for this delegate because the method it targeted (Void Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.OnPageAlert(Object, AlertArguments)) was not enabled for metadata using the Dynamic attribute. For more information, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=616868'
```

It seems that i have to modify the default.rd.xml file in my UWP project. But i don't know exactly how to.

I added

```
<Type Name="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform" Serialize="Required All" Dynamic="Required All"/>
```

but with no result. Same exception as before. 
Can someone give me the hint, how to solve that issue?

cheers,
Chris

Comment: Not so sure whether it works but official doc shares something related to this kind of exception. See [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Target_Invocation_Exception_when_using_Compile_with_.NET_Native_tool_chain) What about give it a try?

Comment: You mean including the Assemby? I already did it with same result ;(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error today in debug mode for ARM64, here .Net Native is always enabled, and here I added those entries to `Default.rd.xml`

```
<Type Name="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsPlatformServices" Serialize="Required All" />
<Type Name="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform" Serialize="Required All" Dynamic="Required All">
  <MethodInstantiation Name="OnPageAlert" Arguments="System.Object" Dynamic="Required" />
</Type>
```

Now the error message was gone.